# Pass gradle step when detekt sucessfully autocorrects

Tags: gradle, detekt

I run detekt with gradle with autocorrect enabled. I fail the build on detekt errors. This results in me running detekt twice for autocorrectable problems:

1. The build fails and is autocorrected.
2. The build passes.

Is it possible to configure detekt to do both in one step? I.e. detekt errors, autocorrect them, and therefore assert that everything is fine by not failing (build step succeeds)?

Comment: can't you create a custom task `A` That will be called after the `build` task, and `A` Task will call the `build` task again after it fails and autocorrect? am not familiar with `detekt` but I am with gradle tasks. 
if you are interested I can show you an example.